# String changes when I malloc another string in C

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I'm currently working on making a shell. I want to separate a simple string into a 2D array. At first it was working perfectly, but now I have a strange problem: my simple string "str" changes after I malloc anything.  For example, if I create a new array like

```
char *tmp = malloc(sizeof(char) * 15));
```

then my `str`, which was `"ls -l"`, will become something like `"  OO"` or `"  A"`.

I've already tried to change the malloc size, but it didn't solve the problem, though it did make `str` change differently.  Her is my code:

```
char **mem_alloc_2d_array(int nb_rows, int nb_cols) {
    char **map = malloc(nb_rows * sizeof(*map + 1));

    for (int i = 0; i < nb_rows; i++) {
        map[i] = malloc(nb_cols * sizeof(**map + 1));
    }
    return map;
}

int what_is_x(char const *str) {
    int x = 2;

    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (str[i] == ' ')
            x++;
    }
    return x;
}

char **try_this(char const *str) {
    int size = my_strlen(str);
    int x = what_is_x(str);
    char **words = mem_alloc_2d_array(x, size);

    return words;
}

char **my_str_to_wordtab(char *str) {
    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
    char **words = try_this(str);

    if (str[0] == '\n' || str[0] == '\r')
        words[0] = NULL;
    for (; str[i] == ' ' || str[i] == '\t'; i++);
    for (int x = 0; str[i] != '\n'; i++, x++) {
        if (str[i] == ' ' || str[i] == '\t') {
            words[j][x] = '\0';
            j++;
            x = 0;
            while (str[i] == ' ' || str[i] == '\t')
                i++;
        }
        words[j][x] = str[i];
    }
    j++;
    words[j] = (char *)0;
    return words;
}
```

What I expect is that in the function `try_this()`, if my `str` is something big like `"ls -l Makefile"` then both `my_putstr(str)` calls will print the same thing, but they don't.

Comment: If you are seeing behavior that seems not to conform to language requirements, and especially if it is associated in any way with dynamic memory allocation, then chances are high that your program is exercising *undefined behavior*.  Problems surrounding (mis)use of memory are often amenable to analysis via a memory-use analyzer such as Valgrind.

Comment: You need to give the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) else it is impossible for us to help you, we do not have a magic crystal ball

Comment: In `mem_alloc_2d_array`, `sizeof(*map + 1)` is the same as `sizeof(*map)` or `sizeof(char*)`, and `sizeof(**map + 1)` is `sizeof(**map)`/`sizeof(char)`. It's not clear what the `+ 1`s are supposed to accomplish.

Comment: @molbdnilo: Phew, your are absolutely right, temp brain laps ... :}

Comment: You should probably just allocate an array of pointers. And then in turn allocate room per string as needed. A 2D array of characters doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what you're talking about with regard to calls to a function `my_putstr(str)`, as neither that function nor any calls to it appear in the code you've presented.  Nevertheless, I can say for sure that your memory-allocation code is screwy, and at least partially incorrect.  Consider this:

```
    char **map = malloc(nb_rows * sizeof(*map + 1));
```

.  What exactly is the point of the `+ 1` there?  Note that `*map` has type `char *`, and therefore so does `*map + 1`.  The `sizeof` operator computes a result based on the *type* of its operand, so your `sizeof` expression computes the same value as `sizeof(*map)`.  I'm guessing you probably want

```
    char **map = malloc((nb_rows + 1) * sizeof(*map));
```

, which reserves space for `nb_rows + 1` pointers.

Similarly, this ...

```
    map[i] = malloc(nb_cols * sizeof(**map + 1));
```

... does not do what you probably intend.  To reserve space for a terminator for each string, that would be better written as

```
    map[i] = malloc((nb_cols + 1) * sizeof(**map));
```

.  But since this code is specific to strings, and the size of a `char` is 1 *by definition*, I would actually write it like this, myself:

```
    map[i] = malloc(nb_cols + 1);
```

You not having reserved sufficient space for your data, it is not surprising that you see memory corruption.

Note, too, that checking for memory allocation failure (in which case `malloc()` returns a null pointer) and handling it appropriately if it occurs are essential for robust code.  Do get into the habit of doing that as a matter of routine, although failure to do so is probably not contributing to the particular problem you asked about.